# datatables colReorder order method with array from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I would like to get a dynamically generated array and pass it into the "order" option of colReorder.

The following works fine:

```
var colOrder = [2,1,0];
$(document).ready(function() {
    dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        colReorder: true
    } );
    dataTable.colReorder.order(colOrder);
} );
```

Note the array colOrder. I can put a variable for that static array into the dataTables order option.

When I test by having javascript alert the contents of colOrder, I get: 2,1,0 (no brackets)

However, the following does not work:

HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" value="2,1,0" />
```

Javascript:

```
var colOrder = new Array($('#test').val().split(","));
$(document).ready(function() {
    dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        colReorder: true
    } );
    dataTable.colReorder.order(colOrder);
} );
```

When I test by having javascript alert the contents of colOrder this time, I get: 2,1,0 (no brackets) -- I see no difference! The DataTable is generated, and colReorder even works, but *the order I provide with that variable doesn't work*.

I get the following error: ColReorder - array reorder does not match known number of columns. Skipping.

Can someone help me? Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/runnerjoe/k47puxux/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your non-functioning code is producting `[["2","1","0"]]`, not `[2,1,0]`. Remove the `new Array` wrapper, as it is nesting the values in another array. You may also need to convert the strings to integers:

```
var colOrder = $('#test').val().split(",").map(function(index) {
   return parseInt(index, 10);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xahww480/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the array now actually looks like [2,NaN,0], so the columns are still out of order. See: https://jsfiddle.net/runnerjoe/k47puxux/1/

Comment: Updated my answer